# Django model: fetch last ForeignKey in one query

Tags: django, django-models, django-annotate

In Django models, I have two database models like:

```
A(models.Model):
    ....
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='my_a')

B(models.Model):
    ....
```

Now, I would like to fetch all B, but have last A be fetched with the same query.

so something like:

```
B.objects.all().annotate(myA=fetch last A)
```

I know for `prefetch_related` but it is too slow.

how can I do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?